# Token-based authentication for Web API in an application which uses SimpleMembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have an *ASP.NET Web API MVC 5.0* application. I've configured an ASP.NET Web API as part of this application (contained in the same project).

I'm currently attempting to add token-based authentication to my Web API. The guide I've been using however has been coding everything using **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity** with Owin.

However, my MVC project is still using the System.Web.Security **SimpleMembershipProvider** - so initialising the membership tables and managing accounts is performed using the WebSecurity class.

So, it looks like I have two options to move forward here:

1. Update my MVC application to switch to use Microsoft.AspNet.Identity so that it will work with my Web API token authentication.
2. Change my Web API authentication code to work with SimpleMembershipProvider

Firstly, is it even practically possible to make my Web API authentication work with SimpleMembershipProvider?

If I update my project to use Microsoft.Asp.Identity, it will involve a bit of work I'm sure. I'm game for doing that but just want to make sure it's not totally trivial to make my Web API token authentication work with SimpleMembershipProvider. Will there be any additional advantages to migrating to use Microsoft.Asp.Identity?

Just to give an example of what I have for my Web API authentication:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    var user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
    if (user == null)
    {
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect");
        return;
    }

    var oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    var cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    var properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
    var authenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
    context.Validated(authenticationTicket);
    context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
}
```

My existing MVC authentication code just uses the WebSecurity methods for managing accounts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end up, I switched over from using the SimpleMembershipProvider to use the Asp.Net.Identity provider. The migration was actually fairly simple.

On my Entity Framework database context, I simply inherited the 'IdentityDbContext' class, e.g.

```
public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

And added this to my OnModelCreating override:

```
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```

In my service which manages accounts, I added code which gets a reference to the new 'ApplicationSignInManager' and 'ApplicationUserManager', e.g.

```
public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
{
    get => _signInManager ?? HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
    private set => _signInManager = value;
}

public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get => _userManager ?? HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    private set => _userManager = value;
}
```

And then each time my code referenced the 'WebSecurity' class I simply replaced those calls with the relevant calls using my UserManager or SignInManager.

ASP.NET Identity also offers some advantages:

- Supports Web Forms, MVC, Web API, SignalR and web pages. Don't need to have different implementations of a membership system.
- Claims based authentication is now an option alongside role-based authentication.
- Easy to enable social logons with Facebook, Google, Twitter or Microsoft Live.
- Supports OWIN.
- No need to code in functionality for account confirmation, password resets and so on - these are out of the box features of Asp.Net Identity.